# Looking to sort a Spark Data Frame by Index using SparklyR

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(Lahman)

spark_install(version = "2.0.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

batting_tbl <- copy_to(sc, Lahman::Batting, "batting"); batting_tbl

batting_tbl %>% arrange(-index())
# Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'INDEX'. 
# This function is neither a registered temporary 
# function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 3 pos 10
```

Anyone know how to use dplyr to sort by index with a Spark (sparklyr) DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I could come up with. Although correct, the `sdf_with_unique_id` function returns some very high sequential values above the 62,000 row. Regardless, it's one way to create a distributed index column with SparklyR.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(Lahman)

options(tibble.width = Inf) 
options(dplyr.print_max = Inf) 

spark_install(version = "2.0.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

batting_tbl <- copy_to(sc, Lahman::Batting, "batting"); batting_tbl
tbl_uncache(sc, "batting")

y <- Lahman::Batting

batting_tbl <- batting_tbl %>% sdf_with_unique_id(., id = "id") # Note 62300 threshold for higher values
batting_tbl %>% arrange(-id)
```